# App not working after Nativebase installation in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-base

[image]

Before Adding the Nativebase App works fine.After adding the its saying the error message.

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions from this thread https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1466?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you followed the installation steps for React Native / Expo, whichever is your project type https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html

Docs mention that if its an Expo app then you need to use `loadAsync`.

Here is the screenshot explaining this

[image]